# Checking non-negative definiteness of $AA^{T}$

Tags: matrices

Given that $A$ belongs to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, Then show that $AA^{T}$ is non-negative definite

I know that $AA^{T}$ is symmetric, so its eigenvalues are real and this matrix is diagonalizable. How to show that eigenvalues are non-negative?

Comment: For the first question, note that $x^T(AA^T)x = (x^TA)(A^T x) = (A^T x)^T (A^T x) = \|A^T x\|^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $AA^\top v=\lambda v$, then multiplying on the left by $v^\top$ gives $$\lambda \|v\|^2 = \lambda v^\top v = v^\top A A^\top v = \|A^\top v\|^2.$$